# sklearn - how to incorporate missing data when one-hot encoding

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I'm trying to keep rows in a dataset that contain missing data.

When one-hot encoding a column (or multiple columns) with sklearn. Is it possible to write a rule that `if currentItem == null` or `if currentItem == 0` then set the output array to all 0s?

e.g.

`A    A    B`  -> `[[1, 0], [1, 0], [0,1]]`

`B    B    A`  -> `[[0, 1], [0, 1], [1,0]]`

`null B    A` -> `[[0, 0], [0, 1], [1,0]]`

---

one-hot encoding:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder


dataset = np.loadtxt("someFile.csv", delimiter=",")
B = dataset[:,1]

encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(B)
encoded_B = encoder.transform(B)

Y = to_categorical(encoded_B)
```

**EDIT - Example Dataset:**
Where A-E are inputs and X & Y and outputs

```
A     B     C     D     E     X      Y
7     6     3     3     2     11     4
5     6     0     0     7     15     7
3     3     9     null  7     12     7
7     null  7     null  7     12     13
null  7     4     6     12    13     4
null  5     7     6     null  14     7
2     6     0     0     2     13     3
7     null  7     null  2     13     7
```

Comment: Do you have pandas?

Comment: I do, is there a solution using pandas?

Comment: What exactly is `dataset`? An array or something else? Add a sample one?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have pandas, this is pretty simple.

```
s = pd.Series(['A', 'A', 0, 'B', 0, 'A', np.nan])
s

0      A
1      A
2      0
3      B
4      0
5      A
6    NaN
dtype: object
```

Use `replace` to convert `0` to NaN -

```
s = s.replace({0 : np.nan, '0' : np.nan})
s

0      A
1      A
2    NaN
3      B
4    NaN
5      A
6    NaN
dtype: object
```

Now, call `pd.get_dummies`, which ignores NaN values.

```
pd.get_dummies(s)

   A  B
0  1  0
1  1  0
2  0  0
3  0  1
4  0  0
5  1  0
6  0  0
```

The solution is the same for a dataframe.

Comment: Would you say one-hot encoding is better using pandas rather than sklearn then?

Comment: @JoeBoggs They have slightly disjoint use cases. Sklearn's Label Encoder is useful when used as part of a larger pipeline. Meanwhile, `get_dummies` is useful for cases such as yours. It also makes it easy to generate a sparse array of encodings, which I don't believe sklearn does. But in general, they do the same thing.

Comment: @JoeBoggs To elaborate the above comment, LabelEncoder (In combination with OneHotEncoder) is useful in cases when data is split into train and test and test do not have all the categories as in train. In that case pd.get_dummies will generate different number of columns for train and test and may produce error in further parts of pipeline, because columns have changed. LabelEncoder will preserve the columns. But when using the data as whole, pd.get_dummies will be better.

Comment: @VivekKumar Spot on description, thanks for leaving a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Or, you can try to use the pandas fillna() method. (Source: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) Let's say you have a DataFrame called `df`. Then, you can do:

```
df = df.fillna(0)
```

to convert all `NaN` in `df` into zeros, before passing it through one-hot encoding.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to replace nan value with 'none' that will introduce additional column
i.e `df_encoding_variables = df_encoding_variables.replace(np.nan,'None')`